# Optimizing Cross Reference Excel VBA

Tags: excel, optimization, vba

Just a quick question.
I have two sheets in my Workbook.  One contains a table of updated "Raw" data, call it Table1.  The other contains a table with the proccessed data (color coded, formated, sorted....) Call it Table2  When I run my sub to update the Table2, my current search algorthms use the Table1 one row at a time, looks for an ID number match in Table2, then updates that row. For small inventories there really isnt an issue.  But larger tables start to take a lot of time. 
I am trying to find a way to cut down on the time, by telling the algorthm not to look at Table2 rows that have already been updated.  Easy enough to slip in a column that conatins a timestamp, I got that covered.
Method 1:
What thought about something like the following. I know this wont work as is, I am summerizing the idea:

```
StartTime = Now
For i = 1 to Last_T1_Row
   RefCell = Table1.range("A" & i).value
   For each T2Row in Table2 that contains Timestamp < StartTime  'I know this is not correct syntax
     ....compare RefCell to T2Row....
     ....not important now.....
   Next Row
     ....code to handle IDs not found....
     ....not important either....
Next i
```

Correct syntax aside, this is just the way to search the "collection" of rows.  Not how to collect them.

What is the best way to collect those rows? I can only think of using ListObject.  But what I am running into with that, is it will require an additional 'For Loop" to populate to the list.  Then I am back where I started.

Method 2:
I thought about using Table2 as my refrence table and each time I found a match in Table1 removing the entire row and shifting up.  That way there is less to search every time.  I forget the term for it but I believe the time shrinks exponentaily as it loops through using that method.  But I am trying to NOT delete data.  So I am wondering if there are any other ideas before I commit to this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that loading a range into a variant array speeds up comparison.

1. Reference range / value only once

   ```
   varRef = Table1.Range("A1").Resize(Last_T1_Row).Value
   For i = 1 to Last_T1_Row ' Also, ubound(varRef)
       RefCell = varRef(i, 1)
   ```
2. Add an "Exit For" / GoTo to cheat your way out of your loop.

   ```
   For each T2Row in Table2 
       ....compare RefCell to T2Row....
       if RefCell >= T2Cell then
            ' do things.
            Exit for
       end if
       ....not important now.....
   Next Row
   ```
3. I hear you that doing an additional loop after the fact is likely unnecessary. Maybe consider overwriting the data in place?

   ```
    ' do things --> Load values.
      for k = 1 to ubound(varT2, 2)
          varT2(j, k) = varRef(i, k) ' provided you've read the whole range of values you care about
      next k
   ```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try, and let you know how it works out!